# Consume a java web service in .Net

Tags: java, .net, wcf, soap, webservice-client

I have a simple java web service for which request xml look like below.

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.jfoundation.com/WebService/WebServiceService">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <airline xmlns="http://www.jfoundation.com/ws/security/">
         <Code>CMB</Code>
      </airline>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>username_here</Username>
            <Password>password_here</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
      </Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:registerUser>
         <userDetailsRQ>
            <emailID>email_here</emailID>
            <fax>fax_number_here</fax>
            <mobile>mobile_phone_number_here</mobile>
         </userDetailsRQ>
      </web:registerUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, i am trying to consume this web service in .Net 4.0, i am able to create the service reference and create the proxy object using the framework generated class. But i don't know how to pass the soap header details via the client.

Below is the code snippet which calls the Web service. But it fails since i am not able to pass the header which captures following information such as **Code, Username, Password**

```
  WebServiceClient objClientProxy = new WebServiceClient();
  registerUserDetailsRQ objUserDetailsEntity = new registerUserDetailsRQ() { emailID = "", fax = "", mobile = ""};
  objClientProxy.registerUser(objUserDetailsEntity);
```

Appreciate if someone can help on this..

Comment: @BartoszKP Thanks, But that did not work, However i was able to find solution after some trouble. [Here](http://shanmohan.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/customizing-the-soap-header-with-messageinspector-on-wcf-call/) i have documented the flow and code if in case anyone would be interested.

Comment: Please consider posting this also as an answer here - so it will be helpful to other SO users.